# How to alert quantity increase and quantity decrease value using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".qty-increase, .qty-decrease").click(function(event){
            id = this.id;
            quantity = $("#input-quantity1_"+id).val();
            alert(quantity);
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="input-content">
    <div class="box-qty">
        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" id="input-quantity1_<?php echo $row_cart['id']; ?>" class="input-text qty">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="44">
        <div class="qty-arrows" style="margin-top: -40px;">
            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('input-quantity1');
        var qty = qty_el.value;if (!isNaN(qty))qty_el.value++;return false;" id="<?php echo $row_cart['id']; ?>" class="qty-increase">

            <input type="button" value="-" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('input-quantity1');
        var qty = qty_el.value;if (!isNaN(qty))qty_el.value--;return false;" id="<?php echo $row_cart['id']; ?>" class="qty-decrease">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code I have quantity increase and quantity decrease type buttons. When I click on `qty-increase` then value increases. Similarly in case of decrease. Now, what happens when I click on `qty-increase` is that it alerts value `1` only and value remains the same. So, how can I get value if I increase or decrease? Please help me.

Comment: Why do you have two codes: jquery-event and code in `onclick`?

Comment: I don’t understand your problem description. But these inline event handlers look really ugly, so the first thing I would do is rewrite that to use jQuery event handling as well.

Comment: As you see in when you do add to cart any product then you have see `quantity increase and decrease' by click on `+` sign and `-` sign. This is the same thing and I am unable to get value from both @misorude

Comment: `qty_el = document.getElementById('input-quantity1');` There is no element with id = `input-quantity1`

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".qty-increase").click(function(event){
            id = this.id;
            quantity = $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val();
            quantity =  parseInt(quantity)+1;
            $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val(quantity);
        });

        $(".qty-decrease").click(function(event){
            id = this.id;
            quantity = $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val();
            quantity =  parseInt(quantity)-1;
            if(quantity > 0){
                $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val(quantity);
            }else{
                $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val(0);
                alert('Item is remove in cart')
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

let me know if you still get the error.

Update:-

```
   <div class="box-qty">
        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" id="input-quantity1_<?php echo $row_cart['id']; ?>" class="input-text qty">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="44">
        <div class="qty-arrows" style="margin-top: -40px;">
            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="cart_value('add',<?php echo $row_cart['id']; ?>);" id="<?php echo $row_cart['id']; ?>" class="qty-increase">

            <input type="button" value="-" onclick="cart_value('less',<?php echo $row_cart['id']; ?>);" id="<?php echo $row_cart['id']; ?>" class="qty-decrease">

            <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add_value_weclome();">
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    function cart_value(data,id){
        if(data == 'add'){
            quantity = $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val();
            quantity =  parseInt(quantity)+1;
            $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val(quantity);
        }else{
            quantity = $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val();
            quantity =  parseInt(quantity)-1;
            if(quantity > 0){
                $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val(quantity);
            }else{
                $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val(0);
                alert('Item is remove in cart')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, for reply late @Praveenkumar after use your code it revert me `[object Object]`

Comment: @omkara :- You use first code or updated code? both are working properly. Please console log and check

Comment: @Parveenkumar I have used `qtn_inc = $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val(quantity);alert(qtn_inc);` In alert it show [object Object]

Comment: @omkara :- Why you do this? if you need input box value than alert only quantity
`var qtn_inc  = $("#input-quantity1_"+ id).val();alert(qtn_inc);`

after add value